# Scala typesystem. "Deferred" type parameter. Why this works?

Tags: scala, generics, type-parameter

I have been writing some code and it has lead me to:

```
trait SplitStrategy[E] {
  def apply(seq: Seq[E]): Seq[(Int, Seq[E])]
}

object SplitByConsecutiveElements {
  def apply[E](consecutiveValue: Seq[E] => E): SplitByConsecutiveElements[E] = new SplitByConsecutiveElements(consecutiveValue)
  def withConsecutiveValueAsTheHighestCount[E]: SplitByConsecutiveElements[E] = {
    val consecutiveValue: Seq[E] => E = seq => {
      seq.foldLeft(Map.empty[E, Int].withDefaultValue(0)) {
        case (m, v) => m.updated(v, m(v) + 1)
      }.maxBy(_._2)._1
    }
    SplitByConsecutiveElements(consecutiveValue)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(SplitByConsecutiveElements.withConsecutiveValueAsTheHighestCount.apply(Seq(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
  }

}

class SplitByConsecutiveElements[E](val consecutiveValue: Seq[E] => E) extends SplitStrategy[E] {
  override def apply(seq: Seq[E]): Seq[(Int, Seq[E])] = splitSequenceBySequenceOfElements(seq, consecutiveValue(seq))
  private def splitSequenceBySequenceOfElements[E](seq: Seq[E], consecutiveValue: E): Seq[(Int, Seq[E])] = {
    // This is just a dummy operation, not the real algorithm
    Seq((0, seq.filter(consecutiveValue == _)))
  }
}
```

If you look at the "main" method, you can see I call `SplitByConsecutiveElements.withConsecutiveValueAsTheHighestCount` and then I apply it to a Sequence of `Int`. At first, I though it would not compile. But it does compile and works properly.
My rationale for it to not work is that when calling `SplitByConsecutiveElements.withConsecutiveValueAsTheHighestCount` I am creating a `SplitByConsecutiveElements[E]` of unknown type parameter `E`. Then I apply `SplitByConsecutiveElements[E].someMethod`, where `E` is known, but I have already created an instance of `SplitByConsecutiveElements[E]` and not of `SplitByConsecutiveElements[Int]`, for example. Why does this work? It is like the class transofrms itself at compile time?

My head is just a mess right now, I hope I conveyed my concern well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons why it works:

1) Generics on JVM are erased so it's possible to create an instance of `SplitStrategy[E]` without knowing `E`. So no need to "transform the class at compile time".

2) Even if we were on a platform where generic types are not erased (say, CLR for C#) this code still could work.

Compiler tries to infer `E` in `SplitStrategy[E]` based on the context to make the entire expression valid. In you case it successfully guesses that `E` is `Int`.